# Discord.js not playing youtube url

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, youtube, discord.js

```
    let channel = bot.channels.cache.get(config.STUDIEHOKr)
        channel.join().then(connection =>{
        const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zXB8ibh5yk', { filter: 'audioonly' }));
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
            channel.leave();
            console.log('Playing is finished!');
        });    
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is my code from a Discord bot that is playing a song. My bot is running on Heroku. It has worked for a while but today it stopped working. The bot still joins the channel but doesn't play any sound. I don't get any errors in my logs. Can someone help me to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using free hosting on heroku?

Comment: Do you have `@discordjs/opus` and `ffmpeg-static` installed?

Comment: @Tyler2P 
I added this buildpack in Heroku: https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git and via console I did: npm install @discordjs/opus but I am not shure it is installed correctly.

Comment: @Tyler2P Update: when deploying on Heroku, I checked and saw that both were correctly installed.

Comment: @gegs921 Yes, but it worked for a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to host the bot from my pc but playing from YouTube also didn't work. I think there is something wrong with the ytdl-core. So another solution was to put the mp3 files on my Github and play them localy from Heroku, so not from third party YouTube.